# What is a python "cksum" equivalent for very large files and how does it work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, checksum, crc, filehash

I have a problem that i need to validate huge compressed files after download (usually more than 10-20gb per file) against reference checksums that have apparently been generated using cksum

(To be more precise: My python script needs to download large compressed files from the ncbi ftp-server that was supposed to provide md5 checksums for validating the downloads, but instead only provided some different unspecified filehash/checksum values. After some trial and error I found that these checksums were identical to the output of the unix tool `cksum`, which apparently genereates CRC-checksums. So to compare/validate these i need to generate `cksum`-equivalent checksums for the downloaded files.)

It appears that the unix tool `cksum` yields totally different checksum values than the supposed equivalent unix tool `crc32` (or the python `zlib.crc32()` function, for that matter). When googling the problem I could not understand the explanations for why this occurs, especially since they appear to be identical on some systems? So maybe this is because I work on a 64 bit system (but then: who doesn't nowadays)?

using built-in python modules I can easily generate md5- and CRC32 checksums, but none of these are equivalent to the cksum output, neither in decimal nor in hexadecimal representation.

I did find [a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835381/python-equivalent-of-unix-cksum-function) here on stackoverflow pointing to a [snippet](http://pastebin.com/cKATyGLb) that seems to solve this. But while it works for small files, A.) I do not understand a word of it, so I have a hard time adapting it and B.) it does not seem to work well with large files.

for completeness sake: here is the snippet (python3 version):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

crctab = [ 0x00000000, 0x04c11db7, 0x09823b6e, 0x0d4326d9, 0x130476dc,
        0x17c56b6b, 0x1a864db2, 0x1e475005, 0x2608edb8, 0x22c9f00f,
        0x2f8ad6d6, 0x2b4bcb61, 0x350c9b64, 0x31cd86d3, 0x3c8ea00a,
        0x384fbdbd, 0x4c11db70, 0x48d0c6c7, 0x4593e01e, 0x4152fda9,
        0x5f15adac, 0x5bd4b01b, 0x569796c2, 0x52568b75, 0x6a1936c8,
        0x6ed82b7f, 0x639b0da6, 0x675a1011, 0x791d4014, 0x7ddc5da3,
        0x709f7b7a, 0x745e66cd, 0x9823b6e0, 0x9ce2ab57, 0x91a18d8e,
        0x95609039, 0x8b27c03c, 0x8fe6dd8b, 0x82a5fb52, 0x8664e6e5,
        0xbe2b5b58, 0xbaea46ef, 0xb7a96036, 0xb3687d81, 0xad2f2d84,
        0xa9ee3033, 0xa4ad16ea, 0xa06c0b5d, 0xd4326d90, 0xd0f37027,
        0xddb056fe, 0xd9714b49, 0xc7361b4c, 0xc3f706fb, 0xceb42022,
        0xca753d95, 0xf23a8028, 0xf6fb9d9f, 0xfbb8bb46, 0xff79a6f1,
        0xe13ef6f4, 0xe5ffeb43, 0xe8bccd9a, 0xec7dd02d, 0x34867077,
        0x30476dc0, 0x3d044b19, 0x39c556ae, 0x278206ab, 0x23431b1c,
        0x2e003dc5, 0x2ac12072, 0x128e9dcf, 0x164f8078, 0x1b0ca6a1,
        0x1fcdbb16, 0x018aeb13, 0x054bf6a4, 0x0808d07d, 0x0cc9cdca,
        0x7897ab07, 0x7c56b6b0, 0x71159069, 0x75d48dde, 0x6b93dddb,
        0x6f52c06c, 0x6211e6b5, 0x66d0fb02, 0x5e9f46bf, 0x5a5e5b08,
        0x571d7dd1, 0x53dc6066, 0x4d9b3063, 0x495a2dd4, 0x44190b0d,
        0x40d816ba, 0xaca5c697, 0xa864db20, 0xa527fdf9, 0xa1e6e04e,
        0xbfa1b04b, 0xbb60adfc, 0xb6238b25, 0xb2e29692, 0x8aad2b2f,
        0x8e6c3698, 0x832f1041, 0x87ee0df6, 0x99a95df3, 0x9d684044,
        0x902b669d, 0x94ea7b2a, 0xe0b41de7, 0xe4750050, 0xe9362689,
        0xedf73b3e, 0xf3b06b3b, 0xf771768c, 0xfa325055, 0xfef34de2,
        0xc6bcf05f, 0xc27dede8, 0xcf3ecb31, 0xcbffd686, 0xd5b88683,
        0xd1799b34, 0xdc3abded, 0xd8fba05a, 0x690ce0ee, 0x6dcdfd59,
        0x608edb80, 0x644fc637, 0x7a089632, 0x7ec98b85, 0x738aad5c,
        0x774bb0eb, 0x4f040d56, 0x4bc510e1, 0x46863638, 0x42472b8f,
        0x5c007b8a, 0x58c1663d, 0x558240e4, 0x51435d53, 0x251d3b9e,
        0x21dc2629, 0x2c9f00f0, 0x285e1d47, 0x36194d42, 0x32d850f5,
        0x3f9b762c, 0x3b5a6b9b, 0x0315d626, 0x07d4cb91, 0x0a97ed48,
        0x0e56f0ff, 0x1011a0fa, 0x14d0bd4d, 0x19939b94, 0x1d528623,
        0xf12f560e, 0xf5ee4bb9, 0xf8ad6d60, 0xfc6c70d7, 0xe22b20d2,
        0xe6ea3d65, 0xeba91bbc, 0xef68060b, 0xd727bbb6, 0xd3e6a601,
        0xdea580d8, 0xda649d6f, 0xc423cd6a, 0xc0e2d0dd, 0xcda1f604,
        0xc960ebb3, 0xbd3e8d7e, 0xb9ff90c9, 0xb4bcb610, 0xb07daba7,
        0xae3afba2, 0xaafbe615, 0xa7b8c0cc, 0xa379dd7b, 0x9b3660c6,
        0x9ff77d71, 0x92b45ba8, 0x9675461f, 0x8832161a, 0x8cf30bad,
        0x81b02d74, 0x857130c3, 0x5d8a9099, 0x594b8d2e, 0x5408abf7,
        0x50c9b640, 0x4e8ee645, 0x4a4ffbf2, 0x470cdd2b, 0x43cdc09c,
        0x7b827d21, 0x7f436096, 0x7200464f, 0x76c15bf8, 0x68860bfd,
        0x6c47164a, 0x61043093, 0x65c52d24, 0x119b4be9, 0x155a565e,
        0x18197087, 0x1cd86d30, 0x029f3d35, 0x065e2082, 0x0b1d065b,
        0x0fdc1bec, 0x3793a651, 0x3352bbe6, 0x3e119d3f, 0x3ad08088,
        0x2497d08d, 0x2056cd3a, 0x2d15ebe3, 0x29d4f654, 0xc5a92679,
        0xc1683bce, 0xcc2b1d17, 0xc8ea00a0, 0xd6ad50a5, 0xd26c4d12,
        0xdf2f6bcb, 0xdbee767c, 0xe3a1cbc1, 0xe760d676, 0xea23f0af,
        0xeee2ed18, 0xf0a5bd1d, 0xf464a0aa, 0xf9278673, 0xfde69bc4,
        0x89b8fd09, 0x8d79e0be, 0x803ac667, 0x84fbdbd0, 0x9abc8bd5,
        0x9e7d9662, 0x933eb0bb, 0x97ffad0c, 0xafb010b1, 0xab710d06,
        0xa6322bdf, 0xa2f33668, 0xbcb4666d, 0xb8757bda, 0xb5365d03,
        0xb1f740b4 ]

UNSIGNED = lambda n: n & 0xffffffff

def memcrc(b):
    n = len(b)
    i = c = s = 0
    for c in b:
        tabidx = (s>>24)^c
        s = UNSIGNED((s << 8)) ^ crctab[tabidx]
    while n:
        c = n & 0o0377
        n = n >> 8
        s = UNSIGNED(s << 8) ^ crctab[(s >> 24) ^ c]
    return UNSIGNED(~s)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fname = sys.argv[-1]
    buffer = open(fname, 'rb').read()
    print("%d\t%d\t%s" %  (memcrc(buffer), len(buffer), fname))
```

Could someone please help me understand this?

- what exactly is the problem with the difference between `cksum` and `crc32`?
- is it simply the fact that the one is 32bit based and the other 64 bit?
- Can i simply convert between the values produced by both, and if yes how?
- what is the purpose of the crctab in the above snippet and how does the conversion work there?

Comment: Could you not just shell out to a `cksum` binary instead of reimplementing the algorithm (which according to Wikipedia is the Ethernet checksum algorithm) in slow Python?

Comment: Yeah, this is my emergency solution for the time being. But without completely understanding the problem between cksum and crc32 this seems to risk other people getting totally different checksums when running it on their own systems (because apparently ```cksum``` DOES yield the same checksum as CRC32 on some systems)

Comment: Well, to make this implementation work for large files, you'd need to refactor it to read chunks from a stream instead of reading the file into memory all at once. The C source for cksum is available at https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/e361bff8a5ef97fd784a79ce789d8ac6c7e20fc7/src/cksum.c and an CRC32 implementation over at http://home.thep.lu.se/~bjorn/crc/

Comment: could you add the checksum of some small known string, e.g. `hello world`?  I get 1135714720 from both `cksum` and your python code on my system, but am not sure if this is right

Comment: @Sam Mason: the python code is not mine and it is supposed to yield the same checksum as cksum. The problem is: it does not work (well) for very large files. And I cannot adapt it, because I do not understand it

Comment: Looks like `zlib`'s `crc32` is not at all the same thing as the "standard" CRC-32 `cksum` uses; its [tables are different](https://code.woboq.org/gcc/zlib/crc32.h.html), [its per-byte update calculation is different](https://code.woboq.org/gcc/zlib/crc32.c.html#_M/DO1), it [flips all the bits in the input, so an initial value of `0` is actually `0xFFFFFFFF`](https://code.woboq.org/gcc/zlib/crc32.c.html#225), and doesn't seem to do the final padding of the CRC using the length of the input (it just CRCs the raw data). Point is, it's a different CRC.

Comment: To be clear, my intuition on CRC math is bad, so the difference in tables, the per-byte update calculation and the initial flip of bits might all be self-cancelling in some way. But omitting the padding of the data with the length of the data is a giveaway; the checksums are order dependent, so they can't be hiding the length padding in the middle of the checksum operation. If it's not at the end, they aren't doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the why part of your question. All I can say is that the great thing about standards is that you have so many to choose from.

cksum is specified by POSIX to use a different CRC than the more common CRC-32 you find in zlib, Python, used in zip and gzip files, etc. The CRC-32/CKSUM has this specification (from [Greg Cook's CRC catalog](https://reveng.sourceforge.io/crc-catalogue/all.htm)):

```
width=32 poly=0x04c11db7 init=0x00000000 refin=false refout=false xorout=0xffffffff check=0x765e7680 residue=0xc704dd7b name="CRC-32/CKSUM"
```

The more common CRC-32 has this specification:

```
width=32 poly=0x04c11db7 init=0xffffffff refin=true refout=true xorout=0xffffffff check=0xcbf43926 residue=0xdebb20e3 name="CRC-32/ISO-HDLC"
```

The cksum utility on my system (macOS) computes the CRC-32/CKSUM, but it *also* has options to compute the CRC-32/ISO_HDLC, as well as two other actual checksums, the first from the BSD Unix sum command, and the second from the AT&T System V Unix sum command.

There is apparently no shortage of results that cksum might produce.

No, it has nothing to do with 32 vs. 64 bit systems.

No, you cannot convert between the values.

The purpose of the table is to speed up the CRC calculation by precomputing the CRC of every byte value.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried refactoring your code into a class following a similar api to the standard Python `hashlib`:

```
class crc32:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nchars = 0
        self.crc = 0
    
    def update(self, buf):
        crc = self.crc
        for c in buf:
            crc = crctab[(crc >> 24) ^ c] ^ ((crc << 8) & 0xffffffff)
        self.crc = crc
        self.nchars += len(buf)

    def digest(self):
        crc = self.crc
        n = self.nchars
        while n:
            c = n & 0xff
            crc = crctab[(crc >> 24) ^ c] ^ ((crc << 8) & 0xffffffff)
            n >>= 8
        return UNSIGNED(~crc)
```

I've expanded out `UNSIGNED` to try and make it faster and reordered some of the statements to be more similar to the standard [zlib library](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/crc32.c) (as used by Python) while I was trying to understand the differences.  It seems they use a different polynomial to generate the table, but otherwise it's the same.

The above code can be used as:

```
with open('largefile', 'rb') as fd:
  digest = crc32()
  while buf := fd.read(4096):
    digest.update(buf)
  print(digest.digest())
```

which prints out the expected 1135714720 for a file created by:

```sh
echo -n hello world > test.txt
```

The above code should work for large files, but given the performance of Python this would take far too long to be useful.  A 75MB file I have takes ~11 seconds, while `cksum` takes just ~0.2 seconds.  You should be able to get somewhere with using Cython to speed it up, but that's a bit more fiddly and if your're struggling with the existing code it's going to be quite a learning curve!

I've had another play and got performance similar to `cksum` with Cython, the code looks like:

```
cdef unsigned int *crctab_c = [
  // copy/paste crctab from above
]

cdef class crc32_c:
    cdef unsigned int crc, nchars

    def __init__(self):
        self.nchars = 0
        self.crc = 0
    
    cdef _update(self, bytes buf):
        cdef unsigned int crc, i, j
        cdef unsigned char c
        crc = self.crc
        for c in buf:
            i = (crc >> 24) ^ c
            j = crc << 8
            crc = crctab_c[i] ^ j
        self.crc = crc
        self.nchars += len(buf)

    def update(self, buf):
        return self._update(buf)

    def digest(self):
        crc = self.crc
        n = self.nchars
        while n:
            c = n & 0xff
            crc = crctab_c[(crc >> 24) ^ c] ^ ((crc << 8) & 0xffffffff)
            n >>= 8
        return (~crc) & 0xffffffff
```

after compiling this code with Cython, it can be used in a similar manner to the previous class.  Performance is pretty good: Python now takes ~200ms for a 75MiB file and is basically the same as `cksum`, but much slower than zlib which only takes ~80ms.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But could you also give me some pointers on WHY exactly cksum and crc32 are different (both are supposed to generate CRC-hashes, right)? One of the answers at this link: https://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/157116-cksum-does-not-give-me-crc32.html seems to imply that cksum yields the same basic result as crc32 on some systems, but not on others. Wouldn't this mean that these hashes would NOT be the same for identical files on different systems (quite defeating the purpose of checksums in this particular case)?

Comment: with "this particular case" i mean my use-case of validating downloads from a remote server, btw

Comment: that was my reference to "different polynomial to generate the table" compare the table you have with the header file used by [zlib](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/crc32.h).  the constants are all different.  CRC is a family of algorithms, whereas something like SHA256 has a single correct output

Answer (score 0):

If, like me, you have ended on this page with a simple google search of "python cksum", know that the above answers are correct that these are the parameters you have to feed your favorite crc library in order for it to behave like the GNU `cksum` utility (if it doesn't actually already ship CRC32/CKSUM, most do). However, cksum in particular is special and all libraries i could find do not actually implement its behavior correctly, in particular (thanks to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15855329/7611125):

> followed by one or more octets representing the length of the file as a binary value, least significant octet first. The smallest number of octets capable of representing this integer shall be used.

This behavior is not implemented by any crc libraries out there, because it is very special to cksum, and all the libraries leave it up to you to feed them the appropriate data, but this is not documented anywhere but on the [obtuse cksum GNU spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cksum.html#tag_20_19).

In fine, this means that after feeding your crc calculator lib your file, you must also do a little rigamarole with the size of the data you fed it:

```py
from crccheck.crc import Crc32Cksum

good = <known good crc, from running cksum on the file>
good_size= <len(file) as reported by ls -l or cksum)
chunk_size = 32 #file will be read this many bytes at a time
crcinst = Crc32Cksum()
size=0

with open("filepath", "rb") as in_file:
    chunk = "placeholder"
    while chunk != b"":
        #if you're dealing with particularly large (10Gb+) files, you could put a tqdm progress bar here :)
        chunk = in_file.read(chunk_size)
        crcinst.process(chunk)
        size += len(chunk)

assert(size == good_size)

#this is the part missing from all crc calc libraries:
#you have to feed the bytes in reverse order, as per the spec
feedsize = size
while feedsize > 0:
    crcinst.process([feedsize & 0xff])
    feedsize = feedsize >> 8

computed = crcinst.final()
assert(good == computed)
```

EDIT:
In production, using the crccheck library is unworkable for large files, because it is implemented in pure python, and is thus 70 times slower than simply calling os.popen("cksum") (or other facilities) it works fine for smaller files, but this implementation took 45 minutes verifying a 2Gb file, compared to 2 minutes using the cksum utility.

you might have more success using a lirbary like crcfast (i haven't tried) which calls into rust functions which are obviously faster.